# What is $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { f(x) -x }{ x^2 }$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Given that

$$f(x)=8x-f(3x)-\sin^2(2x),$$

find

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { f\left( x \right) -x }{ x^2 }$$

Comment: Do we know anything more about $f$? Is it continuous? Differentiable?

Comment: No we don't know

Comment: That limit doesn't exist. **If** we assume that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-2x}{x^2}$$ does exist.

Comment: You have to change $8x$ into $4x$ in order for the limit to exist.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x)=8x-f(3x)-\sin^2(2x)\Longleftrightarrow f(3x) + f(x) = 8x-\sin^2(2x)\\\Longleftrightarrow (f(3x)-3x) + (f(x) -x) = 4x-\sin^2(2x) $$ 
$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{f(3x)-3x}{9x^2} + \frac{f(x) -x}{9x^2} = \frac{4x-\sin^2(2x)}{9x^2}$$

Let $$\ell = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x) -x}{x^2}$$
Then, 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4x-\sin^2(2x)}{9x^2}= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(3x)-3x}{9x^2} +\frac{f(x) -x}{9x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(3x)-3x}{(3x)^2} +\frac19\frac{f(x) -x}{x^2}= \frac{10}{9}\ell $$
Since $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(3x)-3x}{9x^2}=\ell$$
Hence,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x) -x}{x^2}=\ell =\frac{1}{10} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4x-\sin^2(2x)}{x^2} \sim \frac{1}{10} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4x-4x^2}{x^2}  $$
But this latest limit does not exists.

Comment: You might want to add $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(3x)-3x}{9x^2}=\ell$ as well. It could be helpful for slow people (like me). And shouldn't the $1/10$ be $9/10$?

Comment: Very good answer. +1

Comment: @imranfat it is 1/10 after cancelation

Comment: @GuyFsone. You see, I am a bit slow...

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-x)/x^2 = L \in \mathbb R.$ Then $f(x) = x + O(x^2).$ This implies $f(3x) = 3x + O(x^2).$ Putting this into the given equation and simplifying then gives

$$4x = O(x^2),$$

a contradiction. Thus such an $L$ does not exist.

Comment: +1 I am learning something new here. However, if the limit does exist to such a problem, would your method also work (and be legitimate, as you are assuming that such an $L$ exist to begin with?)

Comment: Given that
 
 $$f(5x)=8x-f(3x)-\sin^2(2x),$$ 
 
 
 find 
 
 
 $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { f\left( x \right) -x }{ x^2 } =?\quad $$  Instead of putting f(x) I put f(5x) now i think it would be easier ?

Comment: Replace f(x) to f(5x)

Comment: @imranfat Yes it would. In fact, it will solve the edited problem with a little extra care, again assuming the limit exists.

Comment: This answer shows that these little-o / big-o notations are quite convenient even though they don't provide any extra information compared to the limit notation. +1

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12f''(0)x^2+O(x^3). $$
Then from $f(x)=8x-f(3x)-\sin^2(2x)$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\bigg[f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12f''(0)x^2+O(x^3)\bigg]+\bigg[f(0)+3f'(0)x+\frac{9}2f''(0)x^2+O(x^3)\bigg]\\
&=&8x-\sin^2(2x)
\end{eqnarray}
which gives
$$ 2f(0)+4f'(0)x+5f''(0)x^2+O(x^3)=8x-\sin^2(2x). $$
Noting that $\sin(2x)\approx 2x$ and hence
$$f(0)=0,f'(0)=2,f''(0)=-\frac{4}{5}. $$
So
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-x}{x^2}=\frac{f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12f''(0)x^2+O(x^3)-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\frac{2}{5}x^2}{x^2}=DNE.$$